# Redistimeseries python client library - support to issue optional field 'Latest' for methods Get, Mget, Range?

Tags: python, redis, redistimeseries

i need help with redistimeseries python client. When i use redisclientobject.range() method of python client, i am unable to provide the optional field [Latest]. is it not supported by python library?.. using "Latest" is critical for me because, when i do aggregation, i need the ongoing bucket data (partial).
the same problem is observed with get, mget functions too.

Background. : i am storing live stock data (ticks) and i use compaction (aggregation) by creating rule. At the same time, i need to plot the live tick data on the chart which means i need the latest ongoing compaction data .
Whereas when i  use redis cli and issue ts.range key - + latest , i get the ongoing compaction. But in Python client library i do not know if it is possible. I have checked the def range() method of the Client class and i believe that the optional field 'Latest' is not implemented

on the redis cli below are the results

> > TS.RANGE VWAP:ticks:MCX:CRUDEOIL22SEPFUT 1662717300000 1662791113000 latest

////

1. 1. (integer) 1662717300000
   2. 738244
2. 1. (integer) 1662717600000
   2. 724450

and without latest,

> > TS.RANGE VWAP:5min:MCX:CRUDEOIL22SEPFUT 1662717300000 1662791113000

1. 1. (integer) 1662717300000
   2. 738244

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the latest redis-py (4.4.0rc1)?

https://github.com/redis/redis-py/pull/2296

https://github.com/redis/redis-py/releases/tag/v4.4.0rc1

Note that RedisTimeSeries 1.8 is still a release candidate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was using redis 3.5.3 and just updated 4.3.4. Even the latest version 4.3.4 doesn't seem to have "Latest" field.

Comment: That's correct. You need to use the 4.4.0rc1 pre-release.

Comment: Yes, I could see the support for "Latest" optional field in the git hub release. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

I have subclassed the client and modified the get method as follows (actually renamed get method to myget  instead of overriding)

class myRedisTSClient(Client):
def **init**(self, conn=None, *args, **kwargs):
super().**init**(conn, *args, **kwargs)

```
def myget(self,key,latest=False) :
    """Gets the last sample of ``key``"""
    if latest :
        paramLatest = 'LATEST'
        logging.info(f"COMMAND TO BE SET : {self.GET_CMD} {key} {paramLatest}")
        return self.redis.execute_command(self.GET_CMD, key, paramLatest)
    else :
        return self.redis.execute_command(self.GET_CMD, key)
```